# Trying to install Realtek Audio97 drivers but can't because they aren't signed

Tags: windows-7, drivers, mac-mini

I'm trying to install the Realtek Audio97 sound driver from the [Realtek driver download page](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=23&PFid=23&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) for Windows 7.

Every time I try to run the installer I get the error message:

> "Windows Can't verify the publisher of this driver".

No matter how many times I select "Install this driver anyway", it just keeps coming back in a forever loop to that same popup window.

Comment: Do you actually need AC97? IIRC, Realtek High Definition Audio Codec superseded AC97 and ac97 is need only for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the installation as Administrator?

If yes try this.

Go to start type CMD prompt then copy and paste this (this will disable digital driver signing authentication)

```
bcdedit.exe -set loadoptions DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON
```

Comment: Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Will you Type UAC into the windows search and turn it off. Try install then

Comment: UAC was and is disabled.

Comment: It's also the home edition so I there's no gpedit.msc option either.

Comment: "testsigning on" does not allow you to load unsigned drivers. It enables loading of drivers that have been signed with a "test certificate", which anyone can get (i.e. it does not provide traceability of authorship).